# Updating Multiple Fileds with logged in user and SHA1 Password

Tags: php, mysql, ezsql

I've been looking around and can't find a place that is showing me an effective way to do this. Currently I have a query that runs when the user submits a form:

```
$query = "UPDATE user SET username='$_POST[username]',
nicename='$_POST[nicename]', 
email='$_POST[email]', 
password=(SHA1)'$_POST[password]', 
position='$_POST[position]', 
race='$_POST[race]', 
type='$_POST[type]' WHERE username=$_SESSION[admin_login]";
```

I'm not sure on how to get this to actually work correctly. Sorry if it's been asked before, but I can't find a good solution to this anywhere. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The user has a form to fill out that has a spot for all of their information. After submission it is supposed to update all of their profile information.

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.**  You *really* should be using [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/623041), into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain).

Comment: Suggest you read [The Definitive Guide To Forms based Website Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/a/477578/623041).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all entire thing is wrong : **Why?**

Because first of all you need to sanitize the input, which you are not doing, atleast you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string` like this :

```
$nicename = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['nicename']);
```

[**Reference**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Secondly you should encrypt the password before you use it in your query like assign your encrypted password to a variable  and than use it in your query, like this :

```
$hashed_pass = sha1($_POST['password']);

//Query goes here
```

and last but not the least instead of using `super global $_SESSION variable` directly in your query, use concatenate it.. like this

```
WHERE username='".$_SESSION[admin_login]."'";
```

Comment: to clarify - you can use `WHERE username=$_SESSION[admin_login]` but it is not considered clean code to do so because you should quote your associative indexes $_SESSION['admin_login'] vs $_SESSION[admin_login]. Plus it leaves the query wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: One could also use MySQL's [`SHA1()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1) function, if so desired.

Comment: @GeekNum88 and eggyal thanks for your info, I edited :) learnt something new, actually if I dont use concatenate for super globals php shows me errors..

Comment: I'm going to try setting all the post functions into variables and then after that I will read up on mysqli escape strings. I've heard of it plenty, but yet to find out what it's really for essentially. (Don't you love us self taught?) Thanks for the info and hopefully I can get something working.

Comment: @MorganGreen As a suggestion, start accepting correct answers

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, always remember [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/). Inserting data like that can lead to SQL injection attacks just like in that cartoon. I'd highly suggest you use prepared statements, this is a feature in both PDO and MySQLi which are methods of reading and writing to a database using PHP, some info on: [PDO](http://es.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and some info on: [MySQLi](http://es.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Whichever you choose to go with doesn't really matter, it's more about personal preference. I like PDO, so here's an example of binding the data and then executing your query using PDO:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);  

$password = sha1($_POST[password]);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE user SET username = :username, nicename = :nicename, email = :email, password = :password, position = :position, race = :race, type = :type WHERE  = :username");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->bindParam(':nicename', $_POST['nicename']);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
$stmt->bindParam(':position', $_POST['position']);
$stmt->bindParam(':race', $_POST['race']);
$stmt->bindParam(':type', $_POST['type']);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['admin_login']);

$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` and `$_GET` arrays can contain dangerous data, so you need prepare data from these arrays before inserting them into DB.

First, you need typecast values to right data types. In PHP you can use followed constructions: `(string)` for string data, `(int)` and `(float)` for numeric data, `(bool)` for boolean data.

Field `email` necessary checked for valid email, use Regex for it.

Follow code is sample of checking data:

```
<?php
    $link     = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, (string) $_POST['username']);
    $nicename = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, (string) $_POST['nicename']);
    $email    = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, (string) $_POST['email']);
    $email    = preg_replace( '/^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.(([0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z]{2,3})|(aero|coop|info|museum|name))$/', $email );
    $password = sha1((string) $_POST['password']);
    $position = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, (string) $_POST['position']);
    $race     = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, (string) $_POST['race']);
    $type     = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, (string) $_POST['type']);
    $admin    = $_SESSION['admin_login'];

    $query = "UPDATE `user` 
              SET `username`='$username',
                  `nicename`='$nicename', 
                  `email`='$email', 
                  `password`='$password', 
                  `position`='$position', 
                  `race`='$race', 
                  `type`='$type' 
              WHERE `username`='$admin'";

    mysqli_query($link, $query);
    mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: So going off the mysqli escape string it looks like it needs two paramters. One being the string and one the connection info. I used `code`$username = mysqli_real_escape_string((string, $con) $_POST['username']);`code` and it's a syntax error and won't run; any ideas by chance? :(

Comment: Awesome. :) I kind of understand it, but it's going to take some getting used to. I appreciate the help. :)